# Can the Laplacian matrix of an undirected weighted graph be decomposed in the form of the Hadamard product ？

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, matrix-decomposition, graph-laplacian

I want to rewrite an incidence matrix M of an undirected weighted graph G into

$ M = W \circ A$

where W is the weight matrix, and $\circ$ denotes a Hadamard product.
Now can someone tell me the factor expansion of the following formulation?

$(W \circ A)^T(W \circ A)\\=(W^T \circ A^T)(W \circ A)\\=?$

I guess there is a relationship among the Laplacian matrix, adjacency matrix and degree matrix.

Comment: The transpose of a matrix product $(XY)^{\mathsf T}$ simplifies to $Y^{\mathsf T} X^{\mathsf T}$, not $X^{\mathsf T}Y^{\mathsf T}$.

Comment: Is $A$ the adjacency matrix? What do hope to achieve, I don't think we can expand more your formula. The relationship between laplacian, adjacency and degree matrix is $L = D - A$, is it what you want?